# Size on disk greater than .vdi image size allocation

Tags: virtualbox

I just noticed I have a repo on one of my virtual box vdis that shows to be 37.2GB on disk (270mb actual size)...however the size of the virtual hard disk was created as a static 10GB image. Everything appears to be functioning as expected. How is this possible? Should I be worried?

Comment: How are you obtaining these sizes?

Comment: @harrymc I have samba setup on the vdi which I use to map a share as a network drive in windows 10. The numbers are obtained via right clicking the repo within the share and selecting "properties". I checked the size of the directory directly on the vm via the cli and the sizes all came back as expected. I'm wondering if this is something specific with how windows is interacting with samba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known configuration problem with Samba.
It is mentioned in at least two bug-reports/feature-requests:

- [Defect 36508 - Windows report cluster size of 1MB used for small file in a SMB share, ZFS says 128kb](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/defect-36508-windows-report-cluster-size-of-1mb-used-for-small-file-in-a-smb-share-zfs-says-128kb.68596/)
- [Samba: Default allocation roundup size is set to 1048576, should be 131072 (and user adjustable)](https://redmine.ixsystems.com/issues/38525)

What is happening is that Windows calculates the disk size taken up by a file
as rounded up to an integral number of disk allocation units, which is the way
things work on a real disk. However, the disk parameter that Samba publishes
is much too large and not realistic.

The parameter is called 'allocation roundup size'.
If its size is left as the default 1408576,
the minimal 'Size on disk' of any file will be 1.00 MB.

The solution is to edit the Samba configuration file `smb.conf`.
Under the `[global]` section find the line containing 'allocation roundup size'
and set it to the real sector size of the disk, probably 4 KB:

```
allocation roundup size = 4096
```

Restart samba for it to take effect.